# C# & Angular - How to make sure they stay in sync

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In Angular you can make use of Resources to make it easy for you to handle (view)models which will be delivered by WebApi Controllers.

Is there any way to make sure, that the calls to your model's properties are still valid except for doing e2e tests?

I am searching for a way to somehow unit test, that my models which will be delivered and the access in html/js are still in sync, so that theses tests fail if i rename a property or something else ...

Comment: You could use tools like Script# to compile C# code to javascript.

Comment: Personally I don't think its worth the effort. Make sure you use data services in Angular so that if a model is modified you will know where to make the changes to sync your app